# get-dummies() getting applied on float parameter

Tags: python, pandas, one-hot-encoding

I have a dataset which contains both numerical and categorical values , but when I apply `pd.get_dummies()`, I am getting dummies of a parameter which contains float value as well.

I tried inserting individual parameters into `get_dummies(df ,columns=[p1 , p2 , p3 ..])` and it works fine, but is there a proper solution for `get_dummies` to ignore a single parameter?

Comment: What do you mean by parameter? A cell value or a column?

Comment: Yes , I meant a column .

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use `select_dtypes` to include / exclude columns:

```
out = pd.get_dummies(df.select_dtypes(exclude='float'))
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC use:

```
out = pd.get_dummies(df.drop('col_not_need', axis=1))
```